# What attack skills can get extra hits with the knockback support gem?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'm running a knockback/bleed build as my first character this league using Jack the Axe (which causes bleeding on hit). Since I'm going to be using knockback anyway, what attack skills can I use that will hit multiple times per attack due to enemies getting knocked back?

I was intending to use groundslam, but I forgot it doesn't work with axes. Sunder does, but it seems to travel too fast to get multiple hits from an attack. Would Ice Crash be a good option? Are there any others?